# Why is my array is not processed?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array of 1000 values.

```
var city = city_str.split(',');
```

It is cities in alphabet order.

I have function which search first word who started in letters which is declared in the argument.

```
function searchWord(letter){
    letter = letter.toUpperCase();
    var letters = city.map(n => n[0]);
    var word = '';
    var flag = false;
    for (var i = 0; (i<= letters.length)&&(flag); i++){
        if (letter == letters[i]) {
            word = city[i];
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    if (word == '') {
        return 0;
    }
    else return word;
}
```

but always return 0. why?

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop condition `(i<= letters.length)&&(flag)` is false right at the outset, because you've required that `flag` be `true`, but you've set `flag` to `false` just prior to the loop. Remember, `&&` means "and".

You probably meant `!flag`. Also, notice that you want `<`, not `<=`, when comparing `i` to `letters.length`. So: `i < letters.length && !flag`

Also note that you don't need those parens, and can I respectfully suggest consistent use of `{}` and indentation. So:

```
function searchWord(letter){
    letter = letter.toUpperCase();
    var letters = city.map(n => n[0]);
    var word = '';
    var flag = false;
    for (var i = 0; !flag && i < letters.length; i++) {
        if (letter == letters[i]) {
            word = city[i];
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    if (word == '') {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return word;
    }
}
```

Or you could just return from within the loop and avoid `flag` (and `word`) entirely:

```
function searchWord(letter){
    letter = letter.toUpperCase();
    var letters = city.map(n => n[0]);
    for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        if (letter == letters[i]) {
            return city[i];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In fact, you can avoid `for` entirely, because if `city` is an array (I assume from `map`), you can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
function searchWord(letter){
    letter = letter.toUpperCase();
    return city.find(n => n[0] == letter) || 0;
}
```

`find` calls your callback repeatedly until it returns a truthy value or it runs out of entries. If your callback returns a truthy value, `find`'s return value is the entry for which the callback did that; otherwise, it returns `undefined`. Since we know the word in `city` won't be falsy, we can safely use `|| 0` to convert that `undefined` to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your loop is not executing due to condition :

```
for (var i = 0; (i<= letters.length)&&(flag); i++)
```

`flag` is set to false. Therefor your loop will not execute.

Change this line to :

```
for (var i = 0; (i< letters.length)&&(!flag); i++)
```